# How does kernel choose IP address if INADDR_ANY is used for joining a mcast group?

Tags: c, network-programming, centos7

I am curious how kernel chooses the interface to join a mcast group when INADDR_ANY is used:

```
struct ip_mreq req;
req.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(someMcastIP);
req.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (void*) &req, sizeof(req))) < 0) {
 ...
}
```

Let's say there are few interfaces on the machine.  How does the kernel choose?

Comment: Here your kernel means Linux kernel or?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894115/7640269

Comment: I added centos 7 tag to be specific.  I read the link you provided but I think my question is slightly different in a sense that I want to understand how kernel will pick up the multicast if I specify INADDR_ANY when I join the multicast group not when I bind -- the link you provided is about binding with INADDR_ADDR.  Thanks!

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Your link is about `bind()`. This question is about multicast joins.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the static IP routing tables to determine where the membership request is sent.